# Combining Excel worksheets

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery

Variations on this question have been asked before, but they either don't address my scenario or the answers go over my head.

I'm working on a project using NYC's School Quality Reports. Each year, they put out school-level data that looks like this:

[image]

The hitch is that, every year, some schools close and others open. I want each school's data for multiple years in the same spreadsheet, so I can do side-by-side comparisons. I don't want to sum or combine the variables/columns from each year; I just want them to be next to each other.

I'm using Excel 2016.

Comment: It depends how automated you want to make this.  Can you manually paste the separate data sheets into the same workbook into separate worksheets?  If so, then I would suggest doing that, and then you can have 1 worksheet that is dedicated to reporting the numbers for all years/schools.  This would be able to be done with a simple vlookup once you have all the data pasted in correctly.  Also, if the formate every year is the same, you can paste everything into one tab and use excels pivot table functionality to show data across years.

Comment: Try adding a column A with the year for the data.  You can keep one running sheet with all the data and you can filter and pivot as needed.

Comment: @user2263572 Between the three responses I've got exactly what I need, thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @Ross Adding the year column was the obvious thing I hadn't thought of, and now I've got it. Thanks so much man!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have Excel 2016, you have more options than ever.

You might use PowerQuery to get data from other workbooks or tables in the same workbok.  Add a year column (sheetname in my case to simulate) to each file or table or whatever.

[image]

You could then append the queries to each other

[image]

Resulting in a list with the year (or in my case sheetname) added in.

[image]

You could pivot the resulting data

[image]

And then chart

[image]

[image]